# Google cloud datastore runquery get as date variable?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using java. This my code

```
RunQueryResponse response = dataset.runQuery("project_name", queryrequest).execute();
```

and response.tostring(). I have all the query I want but there many.
How to get a single value with each field. Like put it in an array or something we can call with for loop or interator.
Thanks

----add code--------
Here some my code:

```
 Iterator<EntityResult> entity_interator = response.getBatch().getEntityResults().iterator();
Map<String, Property> entity;
while(entity_interator.hasNext()){
    entity = entity_interator.next().getEntity().getProperties();
    String first = entity.get("First").toString();
    String last = entity.get("Last").toString();
    String time = entity.get("Time").toString();        
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(last);
    System.out.println(time);
}
```

and response:

```
{"values":[{"stringValue":"first name"}]}
{"values":[{"stringValue":"last name"}]}
{"values":[{"dateTimeValue":"2013-08-28T08:21:58.498Z"}]}
```

How can I get time as date time varible and first name and last name with out {"values":[{"stringValue":" and all junk thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `Property` may contain one or more `Value` objects, and each `Value` can contain one of several different value types (each type has its own field). If your properties are single-valued, you can just take the first one from the list:

```
Iterator<EntityResult> entity_interator = response.getBatch().getEntityResults().iterator();
Map<String, Property> entity;
while(entity_interator.hasNext()){
    entity = entity_interator.next().getEntity().getProperties();

    String first = entity.get("First").getValues().get(0).getStringValue();
    String last = entity.get("Last").getValues().get(0).getStringValue();
    DateTime dateTime = entity.get("Time").getValues().get(0).getDateTimeValue();
    Date time = new Date(dateTime.getValue());

    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(last);
    System.out.println(time);
}
```

Note that this is an example of using the [JSON API](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Cloud_Datastore_API) ([full JavaDoc reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/datastore/v1beta1/java/latest/)). The samples in the [Google Cloud Datastore docs](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) are using the Protocol Buffers API which is structured in the same way but has slightly different syntax.

Comment: The method getEntityResultList() is undefined. I am using google cloud datastore api with app engine to access my another project data.

Comment: Which version of the client libraries are you using, and how are you installing them?

Comment: I'm using com.google.api.services.datastore version: v1beta1-rev8-1.15.0-rc and com.google.api.services.datastore.model

Comment: Install by eclipse. I'm choose add google api. And it download from google.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I've updated the answer to reflect the JSON API instead of the Protocol Buffers API.